# Why can't I use setText() under Button event?

Tags: java, javafx

So I am remaking my kinda complex console program to GUI. However, I am very unexperienced JavaFX user.

```
Label cityNameLabel = (Label) scene.lookup("#cityNameLabel");
cityNameLabel.setText("No text");

Button startButton = (Button) scene.lookup("#startButton");
```

Here I have my Label successfully initiated. At this moment I can still use cityNameLabel.setText(); and it is gonna work.

This continues:

```
startButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    String enteredUrl = linkField.getText();
    if(isValidUrl(enteredUrl)) {
        try {
            cityNameLabel.setText("Test");
            doJob(enteredUrl, cityNameLabel);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }.........
```

When I try to change the label here it won't happen. What I actually need to do is to reference the cityNamelLabel to doJob() method and I want to doJob() method to change it (once it finds the name of the city).

Can anyone give a me a solution that would allow me to do what I want to do? (changing it afterwards from doJob();). Thank you!

EDIT: Here I post my attemp of minimal version. I hope it is enough

```
package net.maty;

public class Katastr extends Application {

final String programName = "KatastRED";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
    try {
        mainStage.setTitle(programName);
        mainStage.setResizable(false);
        BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Katastr.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,500);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        ChoiceBox threadNumberBox = (ChoiceBox) scene.lookup("#threadNumberBox");
        threadNumberBox.getSelectionModel().select(5);

        TextField linkField = (TextField) scene.lookup("#linkField");
        //debug
        linkField.setText("https://regiony.kurzy.cz/katastr/stary-kolin/objekty?strana=");
        //

        Text cityNameText = (Text) scene.lookup("#cityNameText");

        Button startButton = (Button) scene.lookup("#startButton");
        //HERE IS THE THING. EVERYTHING WORKS WELL EXCEPT THE FACT I CANT CHANGE CITYNAMETEXT
        startButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            String enteredUrl = linkField.getText();
            if(isValidUrl(enteredUrl)) {
                try {
                    cityNameText.setText("Example that will not show because it doesnt work.");
                    doJob(enteredUrl, cityNameText);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Chyba!");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Chybně zadané URL!");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();


    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void doJob(String validatedUrl, Text cityNameText) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String url = validatedUrl;      

    String cityName = getCityName(url);
    cityNameText.setText(cityName);

    List<String> parcelLinks = getParcelLinks(url);.....
}


public static List<String> getParcelLinks(String url) throws IOException{
}

public static List<String> getAdressesFromPage(Document doc) {
}


public static List<String> createParcelUrls(List<String> links) throws IOException {
}


public static boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
}

public static String getCityName(String url) throws IOException {
}




}
```

Comment: What happens? Does the code compile? Do you get a NullPointerException? You probably will want to also create and post a valid [mcve]

Comment: It actually works. It does the doJob() method. The only thing that does now happen is not changing the label.

Comment: You may be shadowing the cityNameLabel variable, but it's impossible to tell based on what you've posted. Again consider creating and posting a valid [mcve]. Please read the link.

Comment: Ok, posted. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Oh I guess I solved it.. But really tho. Once the doJob() finishes, everything shows up. I think I need to make a separate thread that will take care of the GUI...

Comment: Indeed you must not block the JavaFX application thread it you want to leave the application responsive. You need to use different threads and if updates to the ui are necessary use `Platform.runLater` on the new thread. Alternatively the `Task` class provides some logic that can handle this for you...

Comment: You appear to be trying to mix a linear console program with an event-driven GUI, and that will never work. You don't need a background thread, you need to create a GUI gets input via the GUI only, not via the console, not `System.in`.

Comment: @fabian: I disagree with your comment. Please see my comment above to see why

Comment: Sorry for that System.in. What I do is that I step by step convert console program into GUI. What I did is that I created an anonymous Thread class that handles the doJob() method. I will see if this is gonna work after adding more features. Obviously in the end there will be no System.out.println(); in my code. Going step by step and hoping I can succeed this way. Thank you for your time:)

Comment: Don't "step-by-step" this. This is your opportunity to re-write from the ground up, using decent OOP-compliant classes and good structure, with strong separation of UI from program logic. Start over.